# Find a window in current workspace and apply some action to it

Tags: xmonad

I think this should be really easy for someone who's good at Haskell but I just couldn't figure it out as I'm bad at it.
Basically I want to search through the list of windows in the current workspace, find one matching some condition and apply some action to it; if not found then create this window.
I had a skeleton code like this

```
import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W
import XMonad.Actions.WindowGo

findWindow condition actionIfFound actionIfNotFound = 
    ifWindow (condition <&&> member W.current) windowFound actionIfNotFound
        where windowFound = ask >>= w -> do actionIfFound w
```

Answer (score 9):

Old post, but for anyone still wanting an answer:

Basically, with `XMonad.StackSet.index`, you can get the list of the windows in the current workspace like this:

```
do
    windows <- gets (W.index . windowset)
    -- something...
```

So `findWindow` can be implemented like this:

```
import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W
import Data.List (find)

findWindow :: (Window -> Bool) -> (Window -> X()) -> X() -> X()
findWindow condition actionIfFound actionIfNotFound = do
    windows <- gets (W.index . windowset)
    let found = find condition windows  -- found has type Maybe Window
    case found of
        Nothing -> actionIfNotFound
        Just w -> actionIfFound w
```

PS: The last three lines could be shortened into `maybe actionIfNotFound actionIfFound found`